# How to get the user object from session in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have just started with the DRF, and I'm going through implementing JWT within my REST API. Previously I have worked with Spring Security on Java based frameworks, where there is a concept of something known as Security Context Holder, so the User object is always be fetched from the context holderwithin the controllers or whereever required. Do DRF provide such functionality where I can get the details of currently logged in user without having to call the database?

Comment: you can access the request object, it has a "user" attribute. Example: `print(request.user.email)`

Comment: Do I need to pass this user object from the front end or is it included by the framework by default? Pardon for my silly queries, I'm still transitioning from the Java world. :p

Comment: [Read this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests) to learn how Django authenticates users.